CiviCRM v5.78.2 upgrade causes Scheduled Jobs list to disappear
I just upgraded to CiviCRM V5.78.2 on Joomla v5.2, and the Scheduled Jobs list disappeared.  The funny part is if I click on the Execute Jobs button, they seem to run, the log shows them as having been executed, but the list is missing.
Anyone else see this error?
Thanks,
Neil

If you open the browser's developer tools window and reload the page, do you get any errors?

It's still there in WordPress - perhaps the "template_c" worth emptying/cache cleared?

Aidan ...
it shows :
18:10:05.496 Source map error: request failed with status 403
Resource URL: https://usafnukes.com/media/vendor/skipto/js/skipto.min.js?4.1.7
Source Map URL: skipto.min.js.map/*@end
18:10:05.497 Source map error: request failed with status 403
Resource URL: https://usafnukes.com/media/vendor/metismenujs/js/metismenujs.min.js?1.4.0
Source Map URL: metismenujs.min.js.map
Files are there, but this may be something that changed from Joomla 5.1.2, to 5.2 ??

Yurg ... that was done on the upgrade per normal.   :(

Well ... version 5.80 returned the display.
